# How to calculate the scale factor of layer to fit crop rect when applying CIStraightenFilter?

Tags: swift

I am making a photo editor app like apple photos, but I can't make a exactly straighten image filter

[image]

I didn't figure what is the correct scale of a layer to fit a crop rect when applying `CIStraightenFilter` to fit image with crop rectangle.